# How do I determine what size of hard drive my computer will support?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm looking for a new hard drive for my machine, because I'm running out of space on the old one.  I'm hoping to get the largest drive possible, because that way I don't have to buy another one for a while.

The difficulty is, I don't know how to find out what the motherboard supports in terms of sizes.  Unless I'm missing something obvious, the spec sheet ([this page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3160#sp) in my case, though I was also wondering more generally) only tells me how many slots it has rather than what drive capacity it is willing to read.

How can I find out?

Comment: Folks seem to have 1 TB HDDs with the mobo, so get the biggest one. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=13-128-400&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Page=6#scrollFullInfo

Comment: that mobo is pretty new. it supports sata. i would guess that it eats whatever you throw at it.

Answer (score 2):

To keep things simplest and most compatable and problem free, add any SATA drive of up-to 2Terrabytes to the Intel sata ports on the board, and configure and format for basic disks (not dynamic) with standard MBR type formatting methods.  A single primary partition, and any logical partitions in the extended space you want.

Like Akira said it will work with anything out there, keeping it under 2T just makes it simpler in the XP and Win7 systems.

Going further into suggestions, but to complicate it : If you keep both drives in the system. What I like to do is Clone the smaller drive over to the larger drive, have a "system primary first partition" on both drives, the old one as the backup. Then from the motherboard Boot menu , you can hop back to an older yet operational system anytime if the other system fails completly.  The older drives system partition can be re-cloned to update it again and again (backup).

If the new drive fails (unlikely) or the system in the new drive is crippled or damaged (likely), this cloned backup can be returned. increasing OS survivability many times over :-)